# How can use case condition while joining the tables

Tags: mysql

> How to join the table based on the case condition

```
 SELECT *FROM TB_MESSAGE tbm
LEFT JOIN TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT tbmr ON tbmr.MESSAGE_ID = tbm.ID
CASE 
  WHEN tbm.`TARGET_USERS` = 'INTERNAL' THEN LEFT JOIN `TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT_ANOM` tbmra ON tbmra.MESSAGE_ID = tbm.ID
  WHEN tbm.`TARGET_USERS` = 'ANONYMOUS' THEN LEFT JOIN TB_SCHEDULED_MESSAGE tbsm ON tbm.ID = tbsm.MESSAGE_ID
  ELSE LEFT JOIN `TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT_ANOM` tbmra ON tbmra.MESSAGE_ID = tbm.ID 
 WHERE tbmr.STATUS = 131
```

Comment: You cannot do conditional joins in mysql. consider joining both tables and selecting the data you need.

Comment: Why the same table `TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT_ANOM` is "joined" in two different condition branches using the same joining expression?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT tbm.*,
       COALESCE(t1.somefield, t2.somefield, t3.somefield) AS somefield
FROM TB_MESSAGE tbm
LEFT JOIN TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT tbmr 
        ON tbmr.MESSAGE_ID = tbm.ID
LEFT JOIN `TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT_ANOM` t1 
        ON t1.MESSAGE_ID = tbm.ID 
       AND tbm.`TARGET_USERS` = 'INTERNAL'
LEFT JOIN TB_SCHEDULED_MESSAGE t2
        ON tbm.ID = t2.MESSAGE_ID 
       AND tbm.`TARGET_USERS` = 'ANONYMOUS'
LEFT JOIN `TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT_ANOM` t3 
        ON t3.MESSAGE_ID = tbm.ID 
       AND tbm.`TARGET_USERS` NOT IN ('INTERNAL', 'ANONYMOUS')
WHERE tbmr.STATUS = 131
```

Because `TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT_ANOM` is joined by the absolutely the same way when `` tbm.`TARGET_USERS` = 'INTERNAL' `` and when `` tbm.`TARGET_USERS` NOT IN ('INTERNAL', 'ANONYMOUS') `` the query (it seems) may be simplified to

```sql
SELECT tbm.*,
       COALESCE(t1.somefield, t2.somefield, t3.somefield) AS somefield
FROM TB_MESSAGE tbm
LEFT JOIN TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT tbmr 
        ON tbmr.MESSAGE_ID = tbm.ID
LEFT JOIN TB_SCHEDULED_MESSAGE t2
        ON tbm.ID = t2.MESSAGE_ID 
       AND tbm.`TARGET_USERS` = 'ANONYMOUS'
LEFT JOIN `TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT_ANOM` t3 
        ON t3.MESSAGE_ID = tbm.ID 
       AND t2.MESSAGE_ID IS NULL
WHERE tbmr.STATUS = 131
```

---

> `LEFT JOIN tbmr... WHERE tbmr.STATUS = 131` is an oxymoron – **Strawberry**

That's true - `LEFT JOIN TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT tbmr` must be replaced to `INNER JOIN TB_MESSAGE_RECEPIENT tbmr` due to this condition. Or maybe the logic needs to move this condition from WHERE clause to ON clause (to joining condition). The question does not contain enough info to decide what variant is correct.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN tbmr... WHERE tbmr.STATUS = 131` is an oxymoron